# Python/ Django- NoReverseMatch at

Tags: python, django, git

I am working on a project that has been written in Python/ Django, and recently fixed a bug within the project (using a local Git branch `dateReceived` to make the changes and fix the bug, then merging the `dateReceived` branch with `master` on my local machine). I tested that the bug had been fixed on my local `master` branch, and when I was happy that it had, I pushed my changes to the server.

However, when working with the live version now, it seems that doing this has broken another part of the website, and when I click the button that takes you to the URL `http://.../adds_omits/, I get an error page displayed in the browser that says:

```
NoReverseMatch at /.../adds_omits/

Reverse for 'export_csv' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'costing/(?P<budget_id>[0-9]+)/export-csv/$']
```

and that there was an

```
Error during template rendering

Reverse for 'export_csv' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'costing/(?P<budget_id>[0-9]+)/export-csv/$']
```

This error message highlights the following line from the template that this URL renders:

```
<a class="button m-r-md" href="{% url 'costing:export_csv' budget.id %}">Export to Excel</a>
```

and the 'Traceback' shows the following messages in bold:

```
return permission_required(required_permission)(view_func)(request,*view_args,**view_kwargs)
```

&

```
return render(request, 'costing/adds_omits.html', context)
```

This second message in the 'Traceback' states that it is coming from `costing/views.py` in `adds_omits`

I don't understand why I'm now getting this error, given that I hadn't made any changes to these files in the `dateReceived` branch that I recently merged with `master`... How can I resolve this error? I don't really want to revert to a previous commit, as this would undo the working fix that I implemented on the `dateReceived` branch...?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first error message :

> Reverse for 'export_csv' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 
>   1 pattern(s) tried: [u'costing/(?P[0-9]+)/export-csv/$']

your url expects an integer (well, a string made of numeric actually), but the call to `reverse` got an empty string. Obviously, either there's no `project` in your template's context or whatever `project` resolves to has no `id` attribute or an empty (`None` or whatever) `id` attribute.